# Autofac Mediatr not find

Tags: .net

My problem

My mediatr Module

```
public class MediatorModule : Autofac.Module
{

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Get).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .As(o => o.GetInterfaces()
                .Where(i => i.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler<,>)))
                .Select(i => new KeyedService("Handler", i)));

        builder.Register<SingleInstanceFactory>(context =>
        {
            var c = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return t => c.Resolve(t);
        });

        builder.Register<MultiInstanceFactory>(context =>
        {
            var c = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();`
            return t => (IEnumerable<object>)c.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(t));
        });

        builder
            .RegisterGenericDecorator(
                typeof(MediatorDecorator<,>),
                typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler<,>),
                "Handler");
    }
  }
}



Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=The requested service 'MediatR.IAsyncRequestHandler`2[[SCA.Prospects.Core.Application.Prospect.Crear+Command, SCA.Prospects.Core.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[MediatR.Unit, MediatR, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

Source=Autofac

Answer (score 0):

Look like you might be missing

```
  builder.RegisterType<Mediator>().As<IMediator>();
```

Source (search for Autofac setup)  https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki